Здравствуйте как билдить в solar 2d в android studios без билда в solar 2d
Здравствуйте как билдить в solar 2d в android studios без билда в solar 2d просто импортировать папку с проектом и собрать в android studios

Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.
